# Best (and fastest) way to store triangles and lines in C++?

Tags: variables, 3d

I've got a few 3D apps going, and I was wondering, what is the best way to store lines and triangles? At the moment, I have lines as an array of typedef'd vectors as such:

```
typedef struct
{
    float x, y, z;
}
Vector

Vector line[2];
```

Now, I could do it like this:

```
typedef struct 
{
    Vector start, end;
}
Line

Line lineVar;
```

Faces could be similar:

```
typdef struct
{
    Vector v1, v2, v3;
}

Face faceVar;
```

My question is this: Is there a better or faster way to store lines and faces? Or am I doing it OK?

Thanks,

James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is pretty much how vectors are represented in computer programs. I can't imagine any other way to do it. This is perfectly fine:

```
typedef struct
{
    float x, y, z;
} Vector;
```

([DirectX stores vector components like this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb172627.aspx), by the way.)

However, 3D intensive programs typically have the faces index into a vector array to save space since the same points often appear on different faces of a 3D model:

```
typedef struct
{
    int vectorIndex1, vectorIndex2, vectorIndex3;
} Face;
```

Comment: @JamWaffles: I should note that faces are typically represented by vector indices instead of the vectors themselves - see my edit.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm just playing around with tiny maths demos at the moment - writing little snippet progs to make sure all the components of the final app (a game) work correctly. I'll be loading models from a file, which will have multiple points in the same place, so I'll definitely look into removing duplicates - thanks for the speed boost inspiration!